# How to select an element by a variable id in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Say I want to select an element with the id 'myID' by a variable id='myID'. 
Usually I would straightforward select the element by:

`d3.select("[id=myID]").attr("fill", "#ccc");`

But how to do that by a variable?
I tried something like:

`d3.select("[id=" + id + "]").attr("fill", "#ccc");`

But that of course returns an error.
Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks in advance, monkian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select an element by ID, you can use the `#` notation:

```
d3.select("#myID").attr("fill", "#ccc");
```

or

```
var x = "myID";
d3.select("#" + x).attr("fill", "#ccc");
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wmT9Q/).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
To assign variable id to d3.selectAll, what I have done is ->

```
            var a=d.data.id;
            var b="\"";
            var position = 0;
            var output = [a.slice(0, position), b, 
            a.slice(position)].join('');
            output += "\"";
            d3.selectAll("[id=" + output + "]")
```

In short what is have done is, I am selecting an element which have some certain id(which is variable for each element), and then appending `"` at start and end of the variable and then passing it to the selectAll menthod of d3.